# Conversion problem in datetime parameter in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a sql server report which have startdate and enddate datetime parameters but when i specify datetime in them the report show error

```
An error has occurred during report processing.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

startdate paramter have value **6/22/2011 12:00:00 AM** when  set as report parameter in C# code, My stored procedure code is

```
create PROCEDURE Price
@Startdate datetime = null,
@Enddate datetime = null    
AS    
declare @sql varchar(8000)
set @sql = 'SELECT CommodityPrice.dtm_Date FROM Commodity 
INNER JOIN CommodityPrice ON Commodity.int_CommodityId = CommodityPrice.int_CommodityId where Commodity.vcr_HSCode is not null ' 

IF (@Startdate <> '')
BEGIN   
        SET @sql = @sql + ' and CommodityPrice.dtm_Date >= '+ @Startdate

END
IF (@Enddate <> '')
BEGIN   
        SET @sql = @sql + ' and CommodityPrice.dtm_Date <= '+ @Enddate
END

set @sql = @sql+ ' order by CommodityPrice.dtm_Date desc'

exec (@sql)
```

How can i remove this issue? I am creating dynamic sql because i have some other paramters as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice; don't concatenate input ;p (as always). You can still use parameters with EXEC, especially with sp_ExecuteSQL. That will avoid all the issues *and* allow query-plan re-use.

NEVER concatenate user input, even in TSQL. ALWAYS use parameters, unless it is *absolutely* impossible to do so.

As a trivial example (in particular to show how the parameter names don't need to match):

```
declare @a int = 15, @b datetime = GETUTCDATE()

declare @sql nvarchar(400) = 'select @x, @y'

exec sp_executeSql @sql, N'@x int, @y datetime', @a, @b
```

we are passing in @a and @b as parameters (mapping to @x and @y) to the SQL in @sql, and executing in a safe, re-usable, cachable way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to CONVERT the value to varchar first, before concatenating

```
CONVERT(varchar(30), @Enddate, 121)
```

You have a second problem in that a datetime can never be empty string: if you assigned an empty string then this becomes midnight in 01 Jan 1900 (which is zero)

The third problem is that for dynamic SQL you need to grant rights on the tables now. Without this the caller only needs rights on the stored procedure.

Finally, you don't need dynamic SQL

```
create PROCEDURE Price
   @Startdate datetime = null,
   @Enddate datetime = null    
AS    
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @Startdate = ISNULL(@Startdate, '19000101');
SET @Enddate = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Enddate, '19000101'), '99991231');

SELECT CommodityPrice.dtm_Date FROM Commodity 
INNER JOIN CommodityPrice ON Commodity.int_CommodityId = CommodityPrice.int_CommodityId where Commodity.vcr_HSCode is not null ' 

and CommodityPrice.dtm_Date >= @Startdate
and CommodityPrice.dtm_Date <= @Enddate
order by CommodityPrice.dtm_Date desc
GO
```

Comment: Given the problem of the empty string - maybe it would be best to hand the DateTime-value as string to the report. Then it would be possible to send string.Empty.

Comment: @Gambrinus: not really. If you mix strings and datetimes you'll get unexpected conversion errors because of DMY, MDY etc.

Comment: Im using dynamic SQL because i have 7 other parameters of type int,varchar and bit

Answer (score 0):

You can also leave the ' arround the date-parameter

```
tableName.DateInTable> @ReportDateParameter
```

That's what works for me in a project.

Sorry - just saw that your sql is linked together - therefore your DateParameter has to be converted to string - as mentioned by the answer above.